# Error running Microsoft Azure computer vision Cognitive Services Read Text container on-prem - Illegal Instruction

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, read-text

I'm trying to run the preview version of a Computer Vision docker container on an Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 on-premises.
I've pulled the docker container `containerpreview.azurecr.io/microsoft/cognitive-services-read:latest` and run like this

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 --memory 16g --cpus 8
containerpreview.azurecr.io/microsoft/cognitive-services-read
Eula=accept Billing={ENDPOINT} ApiKey={API_KEY}
```

the service is up, the swagger is visible and the status endpoint returns OK.

However when I try to use the `/vision/v2.0/read/core/Analyze` endpoint the machine give me this log

```
Initialize on-prem Read 2.0 GA...
/var/tmp/scleXV71Y: line 8:    10 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) dotnet Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.OneOcr.2.0.dll SecurityPrototype=true $ARGS
```

Searching similar issues this seems to be an error related to the AVX support of the machine.
If I check the AVX support on the machine with the command

```
grep avx /proc/cpuinfo
```

it seems to support AVX but not AVX2

However I executed the same steps on a Windows 10 machine that also supports AVX but not AVX2 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Gabriella Esposito Azure cognitive services containers require the host to have AVX2 installed or supported on linux systems. Please check the requirements of host computer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/computer-vision-how-to-install-containers#the-host-computer).

You can try to enable this and run the container again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I cheked the AVX requirement on the machine and it suppurts only AVX but not AVX2, is there a way to install this version or is it a pure hardware feature?
`[user@machine ~]$ grep -q avx /proc/cpuinfo && echo AVX supported || echo No AVX support detected`

`AVX supported`

`[user@machine ~]$ grep -q avx2 /proc/cpuinfo && echo AVX2 supported || echo No AVX2 support detected`

`No AVX2 support detected`

Comment: The [release notes from 7.3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/7.3_release_notes/new_features_compiler_and_tools) indicate that it would be available on hosts that are capable. My best guess would be your hardware might not be supporting it.